# Rewrite url to remove question mark and add slashes in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've spent a couple of hours trying to achieve something I thought was easy. I have `http://localhost/testing_url_document/second.php?id=2` and want to turn it `http://localhost/testing_url_document/second/id/2`. I have achieved to remove the php extension but stucked into the rewriting the site page . In the htacces i have followed the following procedure.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

this is my index page

Index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
        <a href="second/id/2">click here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second.php

```
<?php 
 echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

The second.php should gets the value 2

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it this way inside `/testing_url_document/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing_url_document/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)(/.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+(?:\.php)?)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: working on http://localhost/testing_url_document/second?id=2 but need to work on http://localhost/testing_url_document/second/id/2 ie when we are getting the id using $_REQUEST parameter the id with the value 2 is not getting

Comment: thanks anubhava but I want to make it universally as it  was just the demo

Comment: yes anubhava i have tried and updated rules on /testing_url_document/.htaccess only

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://localhost/testing_url_document/second.php/id/2`?

Comment: object not found,The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: So `http://localhost/testing_url_document/second.php?id=2` works but `http://localhost/testing_url_document/second.php/id/2` doesn't?

Comment: Show your full `/testing_url_document/.htaccess` in question?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93154/discussion-between-anubhava-and-harshit-sethi).

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal configuration that can solve your problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule index.php /index/site/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well... maybe i miss something in your question :) This configuration takes **example.com/index.php?site=Page** address and redirects it to **example.com/index/site/Page** It works great in Apache/2.4.7

Comment: It is working but I want the $_GET variable input to be same as the example.com/index/site/Page i.e $_GET['site']=Page

Comment: we can also get the value of site through $_GET